How to slice a 2D line plot to create a 3D surface plot (or contour plot)? Python
Problem:
I have a CSV file with 2 columns, Time and Intensity, which I can plot to get a very dense line plot. Time ranges from 900 to 11'496 seconds and for each second I have 200 observations.
Instead of having a super dense and quite unreadable Time vs. Intensity plot, I'd like to slice my data into periods of 1 second (= 200 observations) and plot those slices onto a Time vs. Time vs. Intensity plot, either a contour or a surface plot.
The image below is a lot more explicit than what I just described.

Here's some dummy data to illustrate my problem:
import random


dummy_time = range(1, 101, 1)
dummy_intensity = random.sample(range(1, 100000), 100)

df_dummy = pd.DataFrame(dummy_time, columns=["time"])
df_dummy["intensity"] = dummy_intensity

Using the dummy example, I "sliced" my data so as to obtain 10 slices of 10 observations:
df_dummy["time_1"] = 0

t = 1
for i in range(0,110,10):
    df_dummy["time_1"].iloc[i:i+10] = t
    t = t + 1

df_dummy["time_2"] = 0

t = range(1,11,1)
for i in range(0,100,10):
    df_dummy["time_2"][i:i+10] = t

With the image above in mind, I thought I could simply plot time_1 vs. time_2 and add a color dimension with intensity but turns out it's not as straight forward... In order to create surface and contour plots I need the Z data to be 2-dimensional, which it is not and I'm not sure how it can be made as 2D...
I have the intuition that it's something very simple but I cannot wrap my head around it.
I thought this post would solve my issue but using the same logic the 3D surface plot I get really is just a 2D plot:
x = np.reshape(np.array(df.time_1), (10, 10))
y = np.reshape(np.array(df.time_2), (10, 10))
z = np.reshape(np.array(df.intensity), (10, 10))

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z, x=x, y=y)])
fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
fig.show()

If I could get some advice, not necessarily code even some pseudocode to put me on the right track that woud be very helpful. Thank you!

You can use contourf():
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

random.seed(10)


def get_contourf(df):
    df["time_1"] = 0
    t = 1
    for i in range(0, 100, 10):
        df.loc[i:i + 9, "time_1"] = t
        t += 1

    df["time_2"] = 0
    t = range(1, 11, 1)
    for i in range(0, 100, 10):
        df.loc[i:i + 9, "time_2"] = t

    x = np.reshape(np.array(df["time_1"]), (10, 10))
    y = np.reshape(np.array(df["time_2"]), (10, 10))
    z = np.reshape(np.array(df["intensity"]), (10, 10))

    for i in range(z.shape[0]):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
        plt.contourf(x, y, z, levels=50, cmap='viridis')
        plt.colorbar(label='Intensity')
        plt.title(f'Intensity {i + 1}')
        plt.xlabel('Time 1')
        plt.ylabel('Time 2')
        plt.show()


dummy_time = range(1, 101, 1)
dummy_intensity = random.sample(range(1, 1000), 100)
df_dummy = pd.DataFrame(dummy_time, columns=["time"])
df_dummy["intensity"] = dummy_intensity

get_contourf(df_dummy)




If that's not desired, you can also consider using contour3D():
Code:
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

random.seed(10)


def get_surface(df):
    df["time_1"] = 0
    t = 1
    for i in range(0, 100, 10):
        df.loc[i:i + 9, "time_1"] = t
        t += 1

    df["time_2"] = 0
    t = range(1, 11, 1)
    for i in range(0, 100, 10):
        df.loc[i:i + 9, "time_2"] = t

    x = np.reshape(np.array(df["time_1"]), (10, 10))
    y = np.reshape(np.array(df["time_2"]), (10, 10))
    z = np.reshape(np.array(df["intensity"]), (10, 10))

    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z, x=x, y=y)])
    fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500, margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
    fig.show()

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.contour3D(x, y, z, 50)
    ax.set_xlabel('T1')
    ax.set_ylabel('T2')
    ax.set_zlabel('Intensity')
    plt.show()


dummy_time = range(1, 101, 1)
dummy_intensity = random.sample(range(1, 1000), 100)
df_dummy = pd.DataFrame(dummy_time, columns=["time"])
df_dummy["intensity"] = dummy_intensity

get_surface(df_dummy)


Prints



Thank you very much, contourf is exactly what I was looking for.
